# prioritize functions from current module if name collision occurs

Tags: idris

If I want to define a `show` function inside a `Main` module, I have to prepend the module name explicitly like this:

```
module Main

Main.show : Nat -> String
Main.show Z = ""
Main.show (S n) = "I" ++ (Main.show n)
```

Otherwise I get the error `Can't disambiguate name: Main.show, Prelude.Show.show`. Is there a way to tell Idris that my current module has priority, to avoid writing `Main.` everywhere? I'd be fine writing `Prelude.Show.show` to refer to the implementation outside of my module, but I want to just write `show` to refer to `Main.show` since I'm mostly working with that inside my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you only need to prepend the `Main.` on the recursive function call, where Idris doesn't know if you mean `Main.show` or `Prelude.Show.show`:

```
show : Nat -> String
show Z = ""
show (S n) = "I" ++ (Main.show n)
```

But there is no way to prioritize functions. I guess this is sane as you would otherwise need to track all names in all namespaces to understand the code correctly. However, there is the `%hide <func>` directive that removes access to a function. To still access it in other circumstances you could first rename it:

```
module Main

PLshow : Show ty => ty -> String
PLshow = Prelude.Show.show

%hide Prelude.Show.show

show : Nat -> String
show Z = ""
show (S n) = "I" ++ (show n)

foo : String
foo = PLshow 'a'
```